# UI Accelerometer reference

Tags: iphone, ios, accelerometer

I am new to iPhone development. I want to make a simple iPhone application which computes the distance traveled by the user, how much calories are burnt, where the user located is and in which direction he/she is forwarding to.Can anybody provide me the details or approach to follow to develop this application.

Comment: You'll get a better response on Stack Overflow. You don't have to re-ask the question over there, it will get migrated. However, you might want to provide more information and show evidence that you've tried something if you want to get useful answers.

Comment: Not to be negative, but I assume you know the basic problem with inertial navigation; that when you double integrate acceleration, small measurement errors grow to overwhelm any useful information.  You'll need a way to mitigate that.  Commercial systems update their assumed positions frequently with fixes obtained some other way. (Sounds like a fun project, though!)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you go through the [iPhone OS Reference Library](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/index.html). A good sample that relates to accelerometer is  [AccelerometerGraph](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/AccelerometerGraph/Introduction/Intro.html).